# XPATH issue in Orchestration with Error has an invalid token

Tags: xml, xpath, biztalk, biztalk-2016

The XML which I am trying for XPath

```
<Life Version="2.24.0" xmlns="http://A.org/Life/2">
    <LifeResponse id="Response_001">
        <TransRefGUID>3b6418ef-0010-4f81-b67a-bd60db693e76</TransRefGUID>
        <TransResult>
            <ResultCode tc="5">Failed</ResultCode>
            <ConfirmationID />
            <RecordsFound>0</RecordsFound>
            
        </TransResult>
    </LifeResponse>
</Life>
```

The Xpath Expression which I am trying to use ,

> Result = xpath(LifeResponse,"/*[local-name()='Life' and namespace-uri()='http://A.org/Life/2']/*[local-name()='LifeResponse' and namespace-uri()='http://A.org/Life/2']/*[local-name()='TransResult' and namespace-uri()='http://A.org/Life/2']/*[local-name()='ResultCode' and namespace-uri()='http://A.org/Life/2']/@tc )");

Error Received:

> Inner exception: '/*[local-name()='Life' and namespace-uri()='http://A.org/Life/2']/*[local-name()='LifeResponse' and namespace-uri()='http://A.org/Life/2']/*[local-name()='TransResult' and namespace-uri()='http://A.org/Life/2']/*[local-name()='ResultCode' and namespace-uri()='http://A.org/Life/2']/@tc )' has an invalid token

Requirement :

The Variable "Result" is a string and I am trying to store the value coming in TC attribute.

Issue:

When I try to test the XPath with online XPath tester its working fine but through BizTalk its giving error

Comment: I tested your XPath expression and its (correct) result is `5`. So I cannot reproduce your error. However, I didn't test it in [tag:biztalk-2016].

Comment: Ya even when i test the expression in xpath tester its working fine , biztalk its failing

Comment: I think you need to wrap string(..) around your XPath.

Comment: Even with String i am getting the same error

Answer (score 1):

Did you try removing the extra space at the end as below ?

Before - /@tc )");

After - /@tc)");